# Facebook like dynamic viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I am trying to create facebook like viewpager (swipable tabs and proper backstack) I can create swipable tabs but cant handle the proper back navigation. Bellow is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    // private SlidePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter. */
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Fragment currentVisibleFragment = mPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (currentVisibleFragment != null && currentVisibleFragment.isVisible()) {

            FragmentManager childFm = currentVisibleFragment.getChildFragmentManager();

            System.out.println("============================================");
            System.out.println("childFm.getBackStackEntryCount()===  " + childFm.getBackStackEntryCount());
            System.out.println("============================================");

            if (childFm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                childFm.popBackStack();
                return;
            }

        }

        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

Adapter of my class is as bellow

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
            return new FragmentB();
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
            return new FragmentC();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}
```

here is the exteded adapter

```
public abstract class SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    // Sparse array to keep track of registered fragments in memory
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Register the fragment when the item is instantiated
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Unregister when the item is inactive
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    // Returns the fragment for the position (if instantiated)
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

and Fragments are as bellow

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "FragmentA";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setText(TAG);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                /*
                 * IMPORTANT: We use the "root frame" defined in
                 * "root_fragment.xml" as the reference to replace fragment
                 */
                trans.replace(R.id.framelayout_infragment_one, new FragmentA1());

                /*
                 * IMPORTANT: The following lines allow us to add the fragment
                 * to the stack and return to it later, by pressing back
                 */
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);

                trans.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
public class FragmentA1 extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "FragmentA1";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setText(TAG);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                /*
                 * IMPORTANT: We use the "root frame" defined in
                 * "root_fragment.xml" as the reference to replace fragment
                 */
                trans.replace(R.id.framelayout_infragment_one, new FragmentA2());

                /*
                 * IMPORTANT: The following lines allow us to add the fragment
                 * to the stack and return to it later, by pressing back
                 */
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);

                trans.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

//second inner fragment

```
public class FragmentA2 extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = "FragmentA2";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setText(TAG);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans.replace(R.id.root_frame, new FragmentC());
                trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                trans.addToBackStack(null);
                trans.commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

When I am going to frament A2 expected behaviour when user press back is I want to go to Frament A1 but I am going to Frament A.   Fragment B,B1,B2 are same as A A1 A2 resp...

Please help

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I managed it by maintaining stacks by myself

public static HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>> mStacks;
mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
        mStacks.put("TAB1", new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put("TAB2", new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put("TAB3", new Stack<Fragment>());
        mStacks.put("TAB4", new Stack<Fragment>());


//when starting new fragment add that to stack like this

public void pushFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        setSelectedPageN(pager.getCurrentItem());
        mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB).push(fragment);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

       if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals("TAB1")) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_feed, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals("TAB2")) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_chart, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals("TAB3")) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_explore, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals("TAB4")) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_profile, fragment);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }


//When you want to finish
public void popFragments() {
        /*
         * Select the second last fragment in current tab's stack.. which will
         * be shown after the fragment transaction given below
         */

        setSelectedPageN(pager.getCurrentItem());
        Fragment fragment = mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB).elementAt(mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB).size() - 2);
        if (fragment instanceof ProfileContainerFragment) {

            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        } else if (fragment instanceof FeedNewUserGuideline && !isShowFeedTutorial) {

            fragment = new FeedFragment();
        }
        /* pop current fragment from stack.. */
        mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB).pop();

        /*
         * We have the target fragment in hand.. Just show it.. Show a standard
         * navigation animation
         */
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.abc_fade_in, R.anim.abc_fade_out);

        if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals(ApplicationConstants.TAB_FEED)) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_feed, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals(ApplicationConstants.TAB_CHART)) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_chart, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals(ApplicationConstants.TAB_EXPLORE)) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_explore, fragment);
        } else if (ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB.equals(ApplicationConstants.TAB_PROFILE)) {
            ft.replace(R.id.container_profile, fragment);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }


//When user back press

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        try {

            if (((BaseFragment) mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.CURRENT_TAB).lastElement()).onBackPressed() == false) {

                switch (pager.getCurrentItem()) {
                case KeyConstants.POSITION_ONE_FEED:
                    if (mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.TAB_FEED).size() == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        this.finish();
                        // super.onBackPressed(); // or call finish..
                    } else {
                        popFragments();
                    }
                    break;
                case KeyConstants.POSITION_TWO_CHART:

                    if (mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.TAB_CHART).size() == 1) {
                        pager.setCurrentItem(KeyConstants.POSITION_ONE_FEED);
                    } else {
                        popFragments();
                    }

                    break;

                case KeyConstants.POSITION_THREE_EXPLORE:
                    if (mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.TAB_EXPLORE).size() == 1) {

                        pager.setCurrentItem(KeyConstants.POSITION_TWO_CHART);
                    } else {
                        popFragments();
                    }

                    break;

                case KeyConstants.POSITION_FOUR_PROFILE:
                    if (mStacks.get(ApplicationConstants.TAB_PROFILE).size() == 1) {
                        pager.setCurrentItem(KeyConstants.POSITION_THREE_EXPLORE);
                    } else {
                        popFragments();
                    }

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

            } else {
                // do nothing.. fragment already handled back button press.
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```